# android запрос на включение интернета

Tags: android, сеть

Я знаю как узнать наличие подключения к сети. Подскажите как сделать запрос на включение интернета или вывести сообщение, с кнопкой отправляющей его в настройки, чтобы пользователь включил интернет?

Comment: можно с помощью рефлексии порыть `com.android.internal.telephony`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что программно включить интернет вы не сможете. Но вы можете перенаправить пользователя на страницу настроек телефона в случае, если соединения нет.

Так вы можете открыть окно с настройками для включения wi-fi:

```
internetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);
                }
            });
        }
```

И код для обработки результата:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            //вывод ошибки
        } else {
            //здесь должен быть ваш код для работы с сетью
        }
    }
}
```